# How to upload a folder of CSV files into BigQuery?

Tags: database, google-bigquery

I have a folder of 225,000 CSV files, each file with 2-4k rows or so. The total folder size is like 6GB, is there a way to upload the entire folder of files to BigQuery into individual tables for each csv file? It kind of seems like I should use Cloud Storage, but will it fit a folder that big and what's the process of using that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am imagining each CSV file has a unique name and there is some mapping function/algorithm that could be used to map the file name to a corresponding BigQuery table name.  Now we want to consider how we want to map the files to the tables.  I see two possibilities ... the first is to create a new BigQuery table and load the CSV data into the table.  I'm assuming that each file has the same schema.  You could load the files into a GCS Bucket and write a script that for each file in the bucket, creates a table and performs a load.  You are constrained to 100,000 unique loads per day ... so you may have to perform your loading over a couple of days.

Another thought is to use BigQuery external tables and, again, create a table definition but have it point to the CSV on GCS to store the data.

You didn't mention if there is anything in the data that partitions the data back into their individual files.  For example, if a file represents a range of date/time and a field in the data also contains the date/time, you might be able to create a table with ALL the data across ALL the files and then create views on the single table.

From a BigQuery and GCS perspective, 6GB is small ... we should have no concerns with size of the data.  I'm more curious on the volume of files.  What are these files?  Why so many?  How many new files will arrive beyond these?  Do you ever need to "reload" the files (do they ever change?)

Comment: Writing a script to upload each CSV as separate BigQuery table is easy enough to achieve. But I'm worried too about the number or files. OP would end up having >200k tables but as we can read from https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas?hl=en#table_limits "when you use an API call, enumeration performance slows as you approach 50,000 tables in a dataset. The Google Cloud console can display up to 50,000 tables for each dataset". I would challenge the need of having such number of different tables and question the overall solution design. But we have too few information to do so

Comment: @Kolban these are game match data, each CSV file is one match with players' commands/decisions made. Total of 225,000 matches played with each having thousands of in-game commands. But if file numbers are an issue then I just want an overall summary of all files. For example, match number 100 had 2000 total decisions for player 1 and 1800 decisions for player 2, save that to a table. Or player 1 made the same specific decision 27 times throughout the game but player 2 made that same decision only 10 times. Can I loop through all files and make a summary table on conditions like those?

Comment: BigQuery can handle Petabytes of data so 6GB isn't much at all.  Let's assume that every game match has an identifier.  Maybe you can build it out of date/time/location etc.  With the information given, I'm now of a mind that you load ALL your match data into one table.  Depending on how you access, you can partition/cluster ... but even so ... performance on queries should still be good.  With a single table, it opens up the idea to perform queries over aggregations of games.  When you load each CSV file, you can append the content to the single table.